# WPF Rendering: Using DrawingImage vs. DrawingVisual in order to receive a drawingContext

Tags: c#, wpf

i need to render some geometries with WPF. I do not want to use shapes because of their UI overhead. I want to render via the drawingContext. Now there are different ways to reach a drawingContext. As far as i know, one option would be to use the descendants of the Drawing class, for example a Drawinggroup, see:

```
 using(var context = System.Windows.Media.drawingGroup.Open())
      {
        context.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Blue, shapeOutlinePen, polygon);
      }
```

With that i can create a DrawingImage and use it as a ImageSource in order to display, see:

```
   var drawingImage = new DrawingImage(drawingGroup);
   this.image1.Source = drawingImage;
```

The other option would be to use the DrawingVisual class, like this:

```
  var visual = new DrawingVisual();
  using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
         context.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Blue, shapeOutlinePen, polygon1);
         context.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Blue, shapeOutlinePen, polygon2);
         context.Close();
        }

  collection.Add(visual);
```

In this case collection is a VisualCollection that uses a Frameworkelement as its host (parent). This Frameworkelement can be used in the UI in order to display the visual.

Now to my question(s):

- Are there even more ways to achive this?
- How do you decide which way to go?
- What does Drawingimage offer what DrawingVisual does not? (Or the other way 
  around)
- Which consequences does either way have?
- What about performance and/or multithreading considerations?

Thanx for all your Input!

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and straightforward way to use a `DrawingContext` would be an overridden `OnRender` method of a derived UIElement or FrameworkElement:

```
public class SimpleDrawing : UIElement
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext); // not strictly necessary

        // your rendering code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx i will test this (third) approach! However, still undecided wich way to go and why...